# How to use 2 variables in vbscript for InStr Function in VBScript

Tags: string, variables, vbscript

'I need to be able to use two variables, (strings) in the instr function but it will not return proper values, the first example is the style i need. but cant seem to get it to work. any help would be greatly appreciated. ive been working on this for 3 days..its filling me with rage.

```
    Option Explicit
    dim message, searchTerm, position

     message = "bob dole was here"
     searchTerm = "dole"

     position = InStr(message, searchTerm)
     'This always returns 0


     position = InStr("bob dole was here", searchTerm)
     'This returns 5, which is accurate

     position = InStr(message, "dole")
     'This returns 0,
```

Comment: All of them return correct result, at least for me. Anyway, to fill safe use textual comparison as Mitch Wheat suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `InStr(str1, str2)` performs a binary comparison.

Try performing a textual comparison, like so:

```
position = InStr(1, message, searchTerm, 1)
```

[I wondering if it is an encoding issue. Where is the message string coming from?]

Comment: that worked. funny how a simple 1 can change the entire thing. thank you for your help ive been working on this for far too long.